# Help me understand this phrase from a novel.

Tags: meaning-in-context

> The stranger came early in February, one wintry day, through a biting wind and a driving snow, the last snowfall of the year, **over the down**, walking from Bramblehurst railway station, and...

According to OALD, down (n) means very fine soft feathers of a bird or fine soft hair; which I don't think is true in this context.

The excerpt is from the beginning of the novel, "The Invisible Man" by "H.G. Wells".

I'm learning English as a second language, and this book is a part of my school syllabus and has countless other similar phrases. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: Interesting +1 But IMO, I think you already found an answer. So it is **over** the down, meaning, over the cloth made from the fine soft feather. I wish I am correct! Meaning, even the cloth can't protect the cold.

Comment: The [fourth definition on Bing](http://www.bing.com/search?q=down&form=OSDSRC), and similarly in other dictionaries, fits far better.

Comment: @Kentaro I thought of that at first, but I don't really think it means that he was walking through strong wind and heavy snowfall and stepped on a piece of cloth made from soft feather. I don't think the writer would mention such an irrelevant detail at the beginning of a story.

Comment: @Nathan "A gently rolling hill" I agree, I think that might be the correct meaning.

Comment: probably.I interpreted it as ...he was walking through the wind and snow over a gentle not so steep hill. I'm not completely sure though, the question's still open for more answers and comments!

Comment: Words often have multiple meanings, @mettled mike. Do not give up so soon. Consult more than one dictionary. There are quite a few of them online.  In this case, the reference is to a hill, as Nathan Tuggy's comment indicates.

Comment: After mentioning the harsh cold so in detail and suddenly only one phrase for such a hill????

Comment: @KentaroTomono  using "down" for a kind of "hill" is a *regional* term not often used outside of England, and for a very specific kind of hill.  Unless you read literature set in that area, you would not necessarily have heard the term.  Similar would be "tor" for a tall, rocky hill, or "heath" for a type of geography common to Scotland.

Comment: @KentaroTomono  as a possibly related example, consider Azuchi Castle in Japan (安土城).  Most Japanese students would read this as "An Do Joo" because that's how you would ordinarily pronounce those kanji.  But as with many place names in Japan, the actual name derives from (well-known) history.  The only reason I happen to know the name of this castle is from people trying to fit my own name to Japanese characters -- 安土龍  :)

Comment: @Andrew Okii Doc! :) Anyhow, 3 days ago I stumbled upon bunch of probably Australian people who are drunk on the train and I really could not understand even one word they spoke without offense. English dialectic is soo immense. From AA to Scots to Canadian to even Singaporian ( Do Singaporian speak "English"? Don't use Chinese with English together haha no offense too )

Comment: @KentaroTomono Remember that there really was no such thing as "English" until Caxton's printing press gave us a "standard" vocabulary.  His famous example (eggsample?!) was someone travelling about 20 miles from London and finding that the local word for eggs was "eyren".  And as recently as the 1990s, the BBC decided to put subtitles on the Scottish comedy "Rab C Nesbitt" (set in Glasgow and featuring a set of drunks with strong accents) because they thought English audiences wouldn't be able to understand it!

Comment: @mettledmike You might like to know about Torpenhow, where "tor", "pen" and "how" all mean "hill" in three different dialects.  Border areas frequently changed ownership, so the original "Tor" (just meaning "The Hill") became "Tor Pen" ("Hill Hill", thought now to mean "the very top of the hill").  The next wave of immigrants didn't know what that meant, so they called it "Torpen How" ("Hill Hill Hill"), and that gave its name to the village of Torpenhow.  And since the village and not the hill is generally marked on maps, people might now talk about the hill as "Torpenhow Hill"...

Comment: @KentaroTomono  No one understands the Australians.  We just pretend so they don't feel too lonely out there on their big island.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

*Bramblehurst* gives us the important clue in this context. It's a village in the Weald region of south-east England. This region is essentially a broad 'bowl' between two long ridges of chalk hills - the North and South **Downs**.

**Down** in this case is not referring to the direction, nor to the feathers of a bird, but to a [type of hill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Downland). **Downs** are long chalk ridges, typically steeper on one side and gentle on the other, with thin soil and few trees. The famed White Cliffs of Dover are formed where the South Downs reach the English channel.  **Downland** is generally somewhat 'wild', with few roads or paths across it - most roads run through passes and cuts, rather than straight across the hills.

This meaning can be seen elsewhere in literature - *Watership Down* uses downland to great effect, and *Lord of the Rings* has several regions of hills referred to as downs.

So the passage means:

> The stranger came early in February, one wintry day, through a biting wind and a driving snow, the last snowfall of the year, over the **unpopulated hills**, walking from Bramblehurst railway station, and...

Comment: So it should be plural or either archaic.

Comment: No, it's neither archaic nor necessarily plural - it's absolutely current usage (says the guy from a couple of villages over from Bramblehurst), and while it's often plural to refer to the whole system of hills, it's also used to refer to notable or local parts of the downland.

Comment: @KentaroTomono: Note that the dictionary only says "*usually* used in the plural" - not *always*. So the plural is more common, but the singular is also used.

Answer (score 8):

[Down](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/down_3) is an slightly archaic term for "hill" (*dun* in Old English). It both describes a landscape (typically in plural "Downs") and individual hills in singular form, e.g. the [Berkshire Downs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkshire_Downs), the [North Downs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_Downs) and [South Downs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/South_Downs) but also [Watership Down](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watership_Down,_Hampshire), which gave the Richard Adams novel its name.

To deconstruct your sentence in question:

"over the down" refers to "the stranger *came*, not to the snowfall. The sentence has a long list of descriptive clauses in a parallel structure (= each could be removed without influencing the others).

So:

```
The stranger came
       early in February 
       one wintry day
       through a biting wind and a driving snow 
             the last snowfall of the year 
       over the down (= hill) 
       walking from Bramblehurst railway station....
```